# Trouble understanding go function call syntax

Tags: go

I found this example [here](http://thenewstack.io/building-a-web-server-in-go/):

```
func(*myHandler) ServeHTTP(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    // What does this line do??
    if h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]; ok {
        h(writer, request)
        return
    }

    io.WriteString(writer, "my server: " + request.URL.String())
}
```

I am extremely puzzled by this line:

```
if h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]; ok { h(writer, request) }
```

first off, how can it be valid syntactically to declare `ok` after it is assigned to the result of `route()`?

second, if `h` is returned by `route()`, how can it be used in the definition of `ok`???

I am thoroughly confused by this. Gophers, please help.

Comment: The second occurrence of `ok` is not an assignment but the expression of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6) in Tour of Go. It explains that:

> Like `for`, the `if` statement can start with a short statement to execute before the condition.

Given your example:

> ```
> h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]; ok { ... }
> ```

The short statement is `h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]`. The `;` after marks the end of the short statement. The `ok` that follows is the condition. If true, then the code block `{...}` is executed. In that code block you can use all the variables that were assigned in the short statement.

> first off, how can it be valid syntactically to declare `ok` after it is assigned to the result of `route()`?

`ok` is not declared after it is assigned. It is a boolean value, used in the condition.

> second, if `h is returned by`route()`, how can it be used in the definition of`ok`???

It's not definition of `ok`. It's the code block of the `if` statement.

Consider this alternative, almost equivalent writing style:

```
h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]
if ok {
    h(writer, request)
    return
}
```

This is perfectly clear, right? We just split the original code to two steps. But this is not the same. When writing this way, the `h` and `ok` variables are visible after the `if` statement. This is not desirable. It's a good practice to minimize the visibility of variables (also known as the *live time*). The longer a variable is visible, the longer the *window of vulnerability* during which it can be accidentally misused. This syntax of Go is truly great, genius, and I don't know a single other language where this kind of `if` statement is possible.

See also the section on the `if` statement in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: you should run through the Go Tour - specifically the section on Maps: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

The "comma, ok" idiom here is designed to check that the key exists in the map. Doing a lookup on a non-existent key will panic (and likely crash your application).

`if h, ok := route[request.URL.String()]; ok { h(writer, request) }`

- If `request.URL.String()` exists, set `h` and set `ok` to true.
- If `ok` is true, then call the function `h`.
- Otherwise, write the URL to the response (and do nothing further).